# Ruby on rails controller methods issue with Datatables

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datatables

So here I try to add organisation_id column to the dataTable, in order to do that I need to modify this existing index method. here's the code

```
def index
    authorize :upload

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index }
      format.json do
        @uploads =
      policy_scope(add_sort_and_direction(collection: Upload.all,
                                          default_sort: 'updated_at',
                                          default_direction: 'desc'))
      .searching(query: params[:query])
      .page(params[:page])
      .per(params[:length])
        @csv_file_validation_errors_hash =
          CsvFileValidationError.where(upload_id: @uploads.pluck(:id))
                                .group(:upload_id)
                                .count
      end
    end
  end
```

I made some changes and modified it like this

```
@uploads =
  policy_scope(Upload.includes(:organisation))
    .searching(query: params[:query])
    .page(params[:page])
    .per(params[:length])
```

The `'organisation_id'`column already exist in MySQL table, but it won't recognize by .js file that includes dataTables, I already checked if the @uploads return all values including org id and It's verified. Here I added org id in uploads.js file,

```
var $uploadsTable = $("#uploads_list_table").DataTable({
  // ... other options ...

  columns: [
    // ... other columns ...
    { data: "organisation_id" }, // Add the organisation_id column here
  ],

  // ... other options ...
});
```

DataTables warning: table id=uploads_list_table - Requested unknown parameter 'organisation_id' for row 0, column 6. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4